# select object in for loop instead of using foreach in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to use for loop instead of foreach in mvc application in one of my views. I have problem accesing desired objects

foreach goes by every object there is in models

```
@foreach (var cat in Model)
{
     @cat.Name
}
```

and I want to do the same but by telling which object i want to reffer to

This works :) thanks guys!

```
<ul class='kwicks kwicks-vertical'>
@for (float i = 0; i < (float)Model.Count() / 3; i++)
{
    var numObjects = @i * 3;

        <li>
            <ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
            @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {                    
                if (numObjects == Model.Count())
                {
                    break;
                }
                var element = @Model.ToList();
                <li>@element[(int)numObjects].Name</li>
                numObjects++;
            }
            </ul>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: why not foreach ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I updated the first post with why i want to use for loop insread of foreach

Comment: What do you mean by "have problems"? Do you get an error?

Comment: no , but i cant select the desired object, i get errors when i try to use suggestions so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have `IEnumerable<T>` sequence as Model. So for accessing to this in index-based way you need to convert it to list or to array.
Try something like this:

```
@{var model = Model.ToList();}
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{

      /---- 
            here you can say @Model[i].Name ??
      ----/
}
```

Of course it would be better if you change the type of your model from `IEnumerable<T>` to something that supports access to element by index like `T[]` or `List<T>`

UPDATE:
About your algorithm: I wouldn't mess with dividing floats and rewrite it as something like this:

```
var i = 0;
foreach(var mod in Model)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0)
    {
        <li>
            <ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
    }
    <li>Element  @i</li>

    if(i % 3 == 0)
    {
             </ul>
        </li>
    }
    i++;
}
```

Or if you still need 'for' loop I would've considered using a statement:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i+=3)
```

Comment: yeah :) that's exactly what i had problem with :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use int for `i`.

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
      var element = Model[i];
      <div>@element.Name</div>
}
```

Comment: yeah but i had to convert model to a list becaouse of model type (IEnumerable)